# Can we equate coefficients of power series over inequalities?

Tags: inequality, power-series

Let $x>0$ and suppose we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)x^k>\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(k)x^k,$$
then can we conclude that $f(k)>g(k)$ for all $k\geq 0$ ?

My thoughts are that this could be true for finite sums, but not true in general for infinite sums. Is this correct? Are there any related theorems about such equating of coefficients over inequalities?

Update: As some of the answers have pointed out this actually fails in the finite case, e.g. $2x^2+1>2x$, but while the coefficients of $x^2$ works out ($2>0$), the coefficients of $x$ do not ($0>2$ is false). I was also wondering about the other direction too, i.e. does $f(k)>g(k)\implies\sum>\sum$.

Comment: This is not my field, but since an infinite sum is the limite of finite sums, you can only conclude that $f(k)>g(k)$ for all $k\geq k_0$ for some $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$. I mean, $f$ can start being smaller than $g$, and then $f$ grow faster. For example, $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterexample:
we have
$$x^2+2>2x$$
for all $x\in{}\mathbb{R}$, but looking at the coeffecient of $x$, the statement doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2):

It does not hold even for finite sum: for any real $x$, we have that $$1-x+x^2=(x-1)^2+x>0,$$ and therefore
$$1+x^2=1\cdot 1+0\cdot x +1\cdot x^2>0\cdot 1+1\cdot x +0\cdot x^2=x.$$
But by comparing the coefficients of $x$ we get $0=f(1)<g(1)=1$.